# Javascript prototype replace not working

Tags: javascript, prototype

Here I have the following `String.prototype.replace` call;

```
$("#"+index+"stock").html(String.prototype.replace.call(value, /(\d{3})/, "$1" + (value%100000 > 0 ? 'K+' : 'K'), 'g'));
```

This is then displaying

```
910K+000
```

How do I get it to display just

```
910K ?
```

The original `value` is **917000**
A list of possible values are as followed

```
156167
785853
890000
162000
//any 100thousand number
```

Here's the JSFiddle of such question : http://jsfiddle.net/2Q3yY/1/

Comment: Try setting up a fiddle for that, as it's not really clear what any of those variables are ?

Comment: What are some examples of what the original value of "value" might be?

Comment: @adeneo I've updated my question with an included JSFiddle

Comment: @Curtis What if "value" is `917014`? Do you still want the result to be just `917K`?  Your question really is not clear.

Comment: Yes, that's correct @pointy

Comment: What would be truly helpful would be a list of possible starting values, and how each of them should be transformed. (If the only possible starting value is `917000` the problem gets considerably easier.)

Comment: Now I'm a little confused? If the value `917014` it's still supposed to return `917K`? Then what's the point of this, just divide by thousand and add a `K`

Comment: So should the results be `156K`, `785K`, `890K`, and `162K`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
function formatNumber(num) {
  var value = parseInt(num, 10);
  if (value < 1000) return value;
  if (value > 100000) {
    value = value.toString().substr(0, 3) + 'K+';
  } else {
    value = value.toString().substr(0, 3) + 'K';
  }
}
```

and after that:

```
$("#"+index+"stock").html(formatNumber(value));
```